# Запись массива в sql php

Tags: php, sql, foreach

Есть такой код, который выводит (1)(2)(3)

```
foreach ($_POST['bp'] as $bp)
  echo "(".$bp.")";
```

При выполнении такого sql запроса в строку записывается просто (3)

```
$s1="INSERT INTO custom_fields_bp (id, bp) VALUES (NULL, '(".$bp.")')";
$pdo->exec($s1);
```

Как быть?

Comment: вам надо сделать конкатенация в фориче и потом его сохранить базу

Comment: Если вы получаете массив, то можете записать его в базу в виде строки используя `implode(",", $_POST['bp'])`, где запятая служит разделителем, либо можно записать всё в сериализованном видел используя `serialize`

Comment: @RifmaMan а подскажите как место запятых использовать скобки, что бы было так (1)(2)(3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходя из описания и комментария автора вопроса, я сделал вывод, что, в базу нужно записать строчку - (1)(2)(3), этого можно достичь следующим образом:

```html
$temp = '';
foreach ($_POST['bp'] as $bp) {
  $temp .= '(' . $bp . ')';
}

$s1 = "INSERT INTO custom_fields_bp (id, bp) VALUES (NULL, '" . $temp . "')";
$pdo->exec($s1);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, обращайтесь.